# UNC File Path is not working as connection string for an access database located on a network drive

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am attempting to insert new records into an access 2010 database that is located on a network drive with a windows form app developed in Visual Studio 2010 using vb.net.  When using the mapped drive letter in the path the connection string works properly, but when using the UNC path I receive an error telling me that it "is not a valid path".

The working path looks like this...

```
Dim dbSource = "Data Source= L:\server\directory\file.accdb"
```

The path that errors looks like this...

```
Dim dbSource = "Data Source= \\server\directory\file.accdb"
```

Is there something basic I'm missing?  The only difference is the use of the UNC path.

As a secondary question, would there be any issue to just use the mapped drive letter if I anticipate all users would have the server mapped to the same drive letter?

Comment: Are you sure that the two path are equals? `\\server\directory` is a sharename to which the L letter seems to be mapped, so there is another additional subfolder named server\directory? If these are fictional names please show the real paths

Comment: As another test, what is the output of the command NET USE for the letter L typed in your command prompt window?

Comment: if the first one is working then \\ (L's server) \ (L's sharename)\server\directory\file.accdb where L's server is the server the network drive is mapped to and L's Sharename is the sharename.  I woul dnot use mapped drives unless you can guarantee that everyone will be using the same mapped drive letter.

Comment: actual paths are as follows...
UNC: \\drpptv01\data\valve\V&R Databases\test dbases\test cover.accdb
Mapped: L:\data\valve\V&R Databases\test dbases\test cover.accdb

Comment: is drpptv01 the share or server name?  you are still missing one

Comment: Open your command prompt then type NET USE followed by ENTER. You should get the list of your mapped drives. Something is missing in your explanation above

Comment: Steve was 100% correct, I was missing part of the path using UNC and found the missing part using net use from the command prompt.  The entire program is now working perfectly.  Thanks to all who took the time to help!

Comment: And to answer the final part of your question. Use the UNC path instead of a drive letter. You have control on that UNC from your server, while the letter is setted by your clients.